# Align vertex preserving the angle

Tags: modeling, vertices

How to to align those vertices keeping the angle? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Just mirror the object. Or extrude a edge between two verteces as you draw the red line and then snap the other verteces to it in the Z axis.

Comment: I love that you also modelled the arrow for the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple cases with a planar surface, one possible workaround is to use the *Connect Vertex* operator.

Move the existing vertex so they stay above an imaginary line connecting both ends, in such way the shape is convex.

In vertex select mode select both ends and use the *Connect Vertex Path* (from the context menu or <kbd>J</kbd> key) operator to joint then with an edge.

Then erase the surplus area.

[image]